# ListView like activity with different views for each row

Tags: android

I would like to create an activity which looks exactly like this:
[image: layout]

I want to have different views in each row, category bars and the buttons at the bottom. This looks to me like something that should be available in the SDK because i see it very often (new alarm screen for instance). If so then what is it. I know it's very similar to PreferenceActivity but i dont think it's the same thing (no buttons at the bottom, built in views only, maps to app's preferences).

Answer (score 0):

The layout you have shown is preferences. Check [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#tutorial_preferences) out.

Answer (score 0):

That screen shot looks like a PreferenceActivity to me.  You certainly don't have to use it to achieve the same look.  You can add buttons to the bottom of a PreferenceActivity layout or go with custom views in non-PreferenceActivity setup.